# get columns value based on where clause as well as aggregate in single query

Tags: sql, join, aggregate-functions

I am sql noob here, I have a table that has 3 columns

`<table>
<tr>msg_date, msg_type, msg_flag</tr>
<tr>20170207  A          0</tr>
20170207  B          0
20170207  B          0
20170207  A          1
20170207  A          1
20170207  A          1
20170207  C          7
20170207  C          7
20170207  C          7
</table>`

I want to query and show following things

msg_date, "count of rows for this msg_date where msg_flag == 0", "count of rows for this msg_date where msg_type is C"

could somebody please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation here:

```
SELECT msg_date,
       SUM(CASE WHEN msg_flag = 0   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS zero_count,
       SUM(CASE WHEN msg_type = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS c_count
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY msg_date
```